# Is it possible to take a photo using Google Glass without "tap to accept"?

Tags: camera, google-glass, mediastore

I'm following the code here to capture an image with the Google Glass camera.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/media-camera/camera#capturing_images_or_video

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Everything is working fine, except that the camera activity requires the user to "tap to accept". Is it possible to just take the photo after a second or so?

This is how the built-in camera app works, I just say "ok glass, take a picture" and it takes a picture without requiring any additional confirmation. The camera in my app is already being activated by the user with other voice/taps in the interface so this second confirmation tap is undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of opening the Google Glass camera app, you could take the picture yourself: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

This is even mentioned in the GDK reference:

> Building your own logic with the Android Camera API. Follow these guidelines if you are using this method:
>
> - Take a picture on a camera button click and a video on a long click, just like Glass does.
> - Indicate to the user whether a picture was taken or a video was recorded.
> - Keep the screen on during capture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cuxtom Cam [library](https://github.com/krazykira/CuXtomCam) to perform that task that you want.