# Picture on Google Glass without "Tap" cofirmation

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass

I'm trying to get a picture, but with my code, is neccesary to confirm the image through "Tap" gesture.

Here is my code:

```
private void takePicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String thumbnailPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);

            processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
            // TODO: Show the thumbnail to the user while the full picture is being
            // processed.
        }
        else{
            takePicture();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I have see this post:

[Is it possible to take a photo using Google Glass without "tap to accept"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540978/is-it-possible-to-take-a-photo-using-google-glass-without-tap-to-accept)

But I can't get the picture without Tap.
Is there any example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add a mechanism that would enable the gesture detection. In your case it is the TAP gesture. I would recommend putting this piece of code in your `takePicture()` method:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
            // user tapped touchpad, do something
            return true;
        }
        ...
        return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }
```

This would enable you to take picture only when you tap on the Glass and hence confirm. For more details please take a look at this [document](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch).